# Laravel+Vue Chatroom logic and Design

Tags: css, laravel, vue.js

I am creating a Simple Private chatroom on Laravel, so heres some explanation how it works on my app theres a button that toggles a bootstrap modal inside that modal i put the vue component its all working fine, but here's my problem how can i put the one i sent on the left and the replies on right? also im having problem with wome text overlapping the wrapper

> Modal

```
<div id="messagemodal">
  <userprofilemessagemodal-component 
    :chatroom_id="{{ $chatroom->id }}" 
    :user_id="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" 
    :receiver="{{ $data->id }}"
  >
  </userprofilemessagemodal-component>
</div>
```

> Vue Component

```
 <div class="container-fluid p-3 roombody">
   <div v-for="roommsg in roommsgs" v-bind:key="roommsg.id">
     <div class="container">                        
       <p id="roommsg" class="rounded-top rounded-bottom p-1 text-white"> 
         {{ roommsg.message }} 
       </p>                                       
     </div>                    
   </div>
 </div>
```

> fetched Array object Structure

```
id: '',
message: '',
chatroom_id: '',
user_id: '',
receiver_id: '',
created_at: '',
updated_at: '',
```

Can all this be done on a styling? Thank you guys !
PS. I'm not copying all the codes, only the codes that i feel you guys need, but tell me if you can understand :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Vue component, you can manage using CSS class something like that
but you have to write the CSS for that

```
<div class="container-fluid p-3 roombody" :class="sender_participant">
    <div v-for="roommsg in roommsgs" v-bind:key="roommsg.id">
        <div class="container">                        
            <p id="roommsg" class="rounded-top rounded-bottom p-1 text-white"> {{ roommsg.message }} </p>                                       
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In script

```
export default {
    ....
    computed :{
        sender_participant(){
           return this.user_id==this.logged_in_user ? 'right' : 'left';
        }
    },
}
```

You have to check whether sender is logged in user or not. something like above assume `this.logged_in_user` is your logged in `user_id`

there is lots of ways to manage but I guess this is easy for the beginner

Comment: Thank you for the response! im having trouble on how to use it i just copy and pasted it on my code nothing happens but in my vue devtools it is saying the auth user is left but they are aligned the same ty

Comment: for the align you have to write the CSS. you can use like above example it will help you. you have to manage `left` and `right` CSS class

Answer (score 0):

## Update

So I found a way to the thing i want in my chatroom, sharing it to you guys that's having the same problem.

> Vue Component

```
<!-- this is for the logged in user -->
<div id="roommsguser" v-if="roommsg.user_id === user_id">
<p><span>  {{ roommsg.message }} </span></p>
<p id="roommsgtime"> <i> {{ roommsg.created_at }} </i> </p>
</div>
 <!-- this is for the other user -->
<div id="roommsgguest" v-else>
<p><span>  {{ roommsg.message }} </span></p>
<p id="roommsgtime"> <i> {{ roommsg.created_at }} </i> </p>
</div>
```

then on my css

> CSS

```
#roommsguser{
    text-align: right;  
}

#roommsguser span{
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;

    background-color: #0080ff;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

#roommsgguest{
    text-align: left;  
}

#roommsgguest span{
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 3px;
    background-color: #14487C;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

#roommsgtime{
    font-size: 60%;
    color: #ececec;
}
```

Tho im not sure if this is the best way to do this, but it works on my end :)